# how to deal with a special character in server name?

Tags: r, rodbc

how to deal with server name server\se
have message 
Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'driver={SQL Server}; server=server\s"
what i need to do?

Comment: You need to escape the \   `\\s`

Comment: like that "server\\se"

Comment: and I have 
server <- "REPORTS\\SM"
but I need "REPORTS\SM"

Comment: That will give you the single \ that you need.  Give it a try.

Comment: If I use single \ ,r understand it how unscreen \S like not witespase in regular expression.